# How to alert vibrate loop with 10 seconds on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have a screen. I want alert vibrate with 10th seconds, 20th seconds, 30th seconds....
How can I do that ?
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple static method that uses a Timer to accomplish this. You pass in the amount of times to vibrate and the period between vibrations. The phone will vibrate for 100ms every `repeatPeriodSeconds` for `repeatCount` times.

```
    public static void repeatVibrate(final int repeatCount, int repeatPeriodSeconds)
    {           
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            private int repeats = 0;

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ++repeats;
                Alert.startVibrate(100);
                if(repeats >= repeatCount)
                {
                    cancel();
                }                   
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, repeatPeriodSeconds * 1000L);
    }
```

Here's the documentation of the relevant classes:  [Alert](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html), [Timer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html), [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Comment: I put this code in 2ndScreen extend MainScreen. But it effect for 1st screen ( also extends MainScreen) and all others screen  . I want it only effect for screen I choose. Help me

Comment: When ever you are going to new screen then first call the timarTask.cancel(); and go to next screen(means push the screen); Otherwise it runs in background(Because you are not popup the previous screen);

Comment: @alishaik786 but about the 1st screen, how to prevent it runs in background ?

Comment: create a small method(StopTheTimer()) in that check that if timertask!=null then timerTask.cancel(); call this method where ever you want;

Answer (score 2):

This helps you:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{   
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
public LoadingScreen()
{   
    setTitle("Loading Screen"); 
    callTheTimer();
}

public  void callTheTimer()
{
    timer=new Timer();
    timerTask=new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            Alert.startVibrate(500);
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 3000);//For 10 secs give 10000; I am testing this for every 3 secs;
}
}
```

Before push new screen or closing the current screen give **timertask.cancel();**